# How to manage SCNNode in ARKit as i require to switching from ARSCNView to Other view controller many time

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I am working on ARKit app and my requirement for switching from ARSCNView to another Viewcontroller frequently and also need to manage SCNNode in ARSCNView.

Main Issue:

- Sometimes placed SCNNode is moving very fast uncommonly and goes
  out of AR screen.
- Sometimes When I try to put a node on the
  surface it does not judge the surface and floating node in Air only.

I want to put SCNNode on the surface with transform vertically.

Thanks.

Comment: If possible, don't use multiple Views with ARSCNView. If possible add UIs but a new view controller.

Comment: @E.Coms As per my requirement, I Need to switch ARSCNView other ViewController frequently. So I use the same AR session configuration each time which first time created to reduce delay when coming back to ARSCNView again and again. So is it ok?

Comment: If your requirement is flexible, you may get better user experience. That’s common to see jiggle. But you can hidden those uncommon details by not rendering them until they are stable or correct. You know it but your user doesn’t care if it’s not a realtime or precise app

Comment: Actually, In our app user will add SCNNode each time after coming back from other view controllers. So when user will try to add SCNNode real-time on a specific position. So place node it's starting jiggle uncommonly, So it's not good for user experience. So can you give me a solution to stick SCNNode properly with set oriantation.

Comment: Without sample codes, it is hard to know the orientations or  transform vertically.

Comment: @E.Coms Please check below answer with my current sample code. Which I am using right now in my app.

Answer (score 0):

@ E.com Please check below sample code which I am using right now to add SCNNode with transform.

```
let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(ARRectWidth), height: CGFloat(ARRectHeight))
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = UIImage.init(named: "img")
let matirials : [SCNMaterial] = [material]
planeGeometry.materials = matirials

let rectNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
var transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi / 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
transform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(transform, Float(orientation), 0, 1, 0)
rectNode.transform = transform
self.addChildNode(rectNode)
self.position = position
```

Comment: I am busy now. I will let you know when I have time.

Comment: It's still not clear . What the self is? if I add it to rootNode, the rectNode works fine. When did you put the code? how many times did the function called? What is the relationship between rootNode and self?

Comment: 1)What the self is?:- We have created the full class of our SCNNode and adding that class directly to rootNode... 
2) how many times did the function call? :- We are removing all node from rootNode and again adding a new same node with the latest position in every 1 second... 
3) What is the relationship between rootNode and self? :- We have created the class of SCNNode and setting all require data in init() of SCNNode Class.

Comment: Well,  what's the relationship between self and surface.

Comment: Not relation between self and surface, our requirement to put each node only on a surface only. In Self (SCNNode class) we pass the position where we want to put SCNNode.

Comment: There are two questions in your op. I am asking surface is because the second one is about the surface. The code presented here seems having nothing to do with either of them.